# Can I add an automated "other" field using custom fields?

Tags: custom-fields

I have a "Select" field options for one of the custom data set. One of the "select" option is "Other". But I would like user to manually enter data related to "Other" field into another text field. Is it something possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

The way to achieve this natively in CiviCRM without writing any code is to create a second text field in which the user can enter their "other" value.

If you want to further improve the UX you can write a little jQuery which will hide the extra field unless the "other" option is selected.

Comment: Voting you up as you're right - one doesn't necessarily need to hide/show - that would be a quick solution for @Tapash to get the field in without any coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible and easy to configure with webform_civicrm module - for those of you on Drupal! The Drupal webform module has built-in conditionals. You can use it to show/hide any Contact field (core or custom) at any time depending on the value of any field (drupal, core or custom) selected by the user earlier on.

If you're not on Drupal - then you will need to code your own conditionals functionality:

```
-create the Other Text/TextArea field and insert it in the profile
-add some .js to pages that shows a profile with such fields in it
-use jQuery to hide the Other Text/TextArea field by default 
-and to make it show when the Other option is clicked
```

EDIT: re: registering multiple participants: here is an example!

```
-have 4 Child-Contacts in the CiviCRM tab
-ask the user for the #Children they would like to register for the Event (webform field)
-use webform conditionals to show the correct # of Child-Contacts
-of course these fields can even be made to prefill for logged in users!
-but I can't show you that - or you'd know way to much about my kids!
-use the Event Registration section in the CiviCRM tab to create Event 
-Registrations for all!
-(and perhaps mom/dad) - when form is submitted
```

[image]

Comment: In webform_civicrm I was going to suggest using the select_or_other module in conjunction with a CiviCRM text field (switching the widget in the webform to select-or-other).

Comment: And the other would then get stored back into a CiviCRM custom field of your choice [not just live in Drupal]? I never even done that (yet)!

Comment: Only problem with webform is, I cant allow multiple participants registration!!! or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh yes you're missing something! Lots! :-)

Comment: @KarinG Yes, in CiviCRM it would just be a text field, but on the webform you could make it appear as select-or-other. It would store the option selected (or the other value) from the webform.

Comment: You can do entire Family Registrations on one page! Let me find you an Example - and link it to your other Q.

Comment: @Tapash see [this documentation on registering multiple participants](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-EventRegistration) with webforms.

Comment: @KarinG Coleman Thanks both for your kind help!! While you guys typing, I was trying webform. Since I have price sets available for the event, its becoming an issue to show all prices on the form. How do I do this?

Comment: Yes - you can't get civicrm pricesets to display in webform - but you can make your own - calculate your own pricing [and your FREE options don't need to be a price_set] - there are still some limitations into turning webform_civicrm in a complete shopping cart

Comment: I plan on dedicating some time to webform_civicrm module during the upcoming CiviCON sprint in Colorado!

Comment: But the current Answer to multiple event registrants on one page/conditionals and even your other Q (limiting the number of total tickets) - is webform_civicrm :-)!